# Does not print entire data

Tags: java, android

Cant seems to understand why it won't print entire content of the list lables, however during debug, it passes through the entire loop but when during run it only print the first line. Pls help guys. Thanks

```
             lables = dbhelp.Ingresso("First");
                if (lables != null) {
                    for (int i=0;i<lables.size();i++)
                    {
                        posFuncs.printerClearBuffer();

                        posFuncs.printerAppendTextline(lables.get(i) );

                        posFuncs.startPrint(new PosCallbacks.PrintCallbacaks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailed(String error) {

                            }

                        });
                    }

                    // }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you clear Buffer before entering new value..

```
 posFuncs.printerClearBuffer();
 posFuncs.printerAppendTextline(lables.get(i) );
```

**Remove** :: `posFuncs.printerClearBuffer();`